# How to stop NSTimer started on button click in this timer callback method

Tags: objective-c, ios, nstimer

I am having problems with stoping `NSTimer` started on button click. `[timer invalidate]` and `timer = nil;` just do nothing neither when I am trying to stop it `viewWillDisappear` nor in method invoked by method which is being invoked by this timer. However when I start my timer in `viewWillAppear` and invalidate it in `viewWillDisappear` everything is fine.

I suppose there might be an issue in thread I am starting the timer from. Can you help with that?

I looked through all answers here regarding `NSTimer` not stopping, but they didn't help to solve the problem.

The way I initialize my timer:

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(oneSecondPassedSinceRoundStarted) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

The ways I tried to stop it:

```
[self.timer invalidate];
[timer invalidate];
```

Comment: How do you initialize your timer? Also check whether your pointer is assigned.

Comment: Adam, I edited my question and added some code.

Comment: @roman: If you don't get answers that solve your questions, you should not accept random answers. Keep in mind though that you can accept your own answers if you managed to solve the problem yourself instead.

Comment: Could you possibly be overwriting the timer member or nilling it before trying to invalidate it? Also you should be invalidating from the same thread you scheduled from.

Comment: Georg, thanks for your input. By coincidence I have found answer to my own question just yet. 

The thing I am trying to say that the system discourage people for asking too complicated questions. It's like I am badass and refusing to give people reputation or recognition. Not good.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's funny how quick you can answer your own question after you asked for a help. No matter how long you have been struggling to find the answer before by yourself:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(stopTimer) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

And the selector:

```
- (void) stopTimer
{
    [timer invalidate];
    timer = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I have created and tested this:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(oneSecondPassedSinceRoundStarted:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)oneSecondPassedSinceRoundStarted:(NSTimer *)time {
    // Do what You want

    NSLog(@"CALLING!");
}

-(IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"Stop timer!");

    [myTimer invalidate];
    myTimer = nil;
}
```

And it is working nice.

**Note:** You forget to add colon after *oneSecondPassedSinceRoundStarted*.

Comment: I am sorry, I edited my question. Actually I was having problems with stopping timer in my timer's callback method. I am really sorry for misleading you.